# stripe does not create a subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm creating a regular subscription service. Everyone can offer their service and subscribe to it.
but the subscription is not being created

```
errStripe::PermissionError (The provided key 'sk_test_***********************************************************************************************5ERf' does not have access to account 'sk_test_51IFXucFi40vayVzCHn4wI2NLmnRO2f7dq1Bs8YQ5OEq0UfqtfXnBE5Ki4sCqASQjQopnRIUUIcELMkQHGnJlQ51N00BEpN5ERf' (or that account does not exist). Application access may have been revoked.):
```

```
app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:26:in `create'
```

I expect the subscription to be created, but it is not being created. If I play with the data transfer parameters and instead of "account" I write smth like "acccccccccount" in the 35th line of the subscription controller and thereby do not pass the user's key, then the subscription is created, everything is fine, but then it is impossible to view the user's subscriptions and another error will occur.

then a subscription is created, but it is not possible to read the user's subscriptions

```
app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb where line #77 raised:

undefined method `subscriptions' for #<Stripe::Customer:0x55dc id=cus_OZ8JiUXM7tbdhR> JSON: {
  "id": "cus_OZ8JiUXM7tbdhR",
  "object": "customer",
  "address": null,
  "balance": 0,
  "created": 1693685042,
  "currency": "eur",
  "default_source": "card_1Nm032JD03t24L8TuSZbeBce",
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": "alex@gmail.com",
  "invoice_prefix": "830E3B39",
  "invoice_settings": {"custom_fields":null,"default_payment_method":null,"footer":null,"rendering_options":null},
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "name": null,
  "phone": null,
  "preferred_locales": [

  ],
  "shipping": null,
  "tax_exempt": "none",
  "test_clock": null
}
Did you mean?  description
```

subscription_controller:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @service = Service.find(params[:service])
  end

  # Reference:
  # https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions
  def create
    @service = Service.find(params[:service])
    key = @service.user.access_code
    Stripe.api_key = key

    plan_id = params[:plan]
    plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(plan_id)
    token = params[:stripeToken]


    customer = if current_user.stripe_id?
                 Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
               else
                 Stripe::Customer.create(email: current_user.email, source: token)
               end

    subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create({
                                                 customer: customer,
                                                 items: [
                                                   {
                                                     plan: plan
                                                   }
                                                 ],
                                                 expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
                                                 application_fee_percent: 10,
                                               }, stripe_account: key)


    options = {
      stripe_id: customer.id,
      subscribed: true,
    }

    options.merge!(
      card_last4: params[:user][:card_last4],
      card_exp_month: params[:user][:card_exp_month],
      card_exp_year: params[:user][:card_exp_year],
      card_type: params[:user][:card_brand]
    )

    current_user.feature_subscriptions << plan_id
    current_user.update(options)

    # Update project attributes
    project_updates = {
      backings_count: @service.backings_count.next,
      current_amount: @service.current_amount + (plan.amount/100).to_i,
    }
    @service.update(project_updates)


    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription was setup successfully!"
  end

  def destroy
    subscription_to_remove = params[:id]
    plan_to_remove = params[:plan_id]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
    customer.subscriptions.retrieve(subscription_to_remove).delete
    current_user.subscribed = false
    current_user.feature_subscriptions.delete(plan_to_remove)
    current_user.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription has been cancelled."
  end
end
```

devise view w/user subscriptions:

```
  <% if resource.subscribed? %>
    <% customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id) %>
    <% if customer.subscriptions.any? %>
      <div class="p-6 mt-10 text-gray-900 bg-white rounded shadow-lg">
        <h4 class="font-bold text-gray-900">Active subscriptions</h4>
        <ul>
          <% customer.subscriptions.list.data.each do |sub| %>
            <li class="flex items-center justify-between py-4 border-b">
              <div><%= sub.plan.nickname %></div>
              <%= link_to "Cancel Subscription", subscription_path(id: sub.id, plan_id: sub.plan.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I want to create subscriptions and watch user subscriptions

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the subscription integration doc here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements and API references here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions?lang=ruby

Comment: For platform with connected account integration, `stripe_account` should be set as connected account ID instead of a key: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe documentation suffered changes while the project was dead weight. We need **expand for subscription**  and **delete** to change to **cancel**

```
def destroy
    subscription_to_remove = params[:id]
    plan_to_remove = params[:plan_id]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(id: current_user.stripe_id, expand: ['subscriptions'])
    customer.subscriptions.retrieve(subscription_to_remove).cancel
    current_user.subscribed = false
    current_user.feature_subscriptions.delete(plan_to_remove)
    current_user.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription has been cancelled."
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you’re using multiple parts of the Stripe API completely wrong.

That first error, with the test secret key - which you should roll for safety as you’ve given it to everyone - looks like you are using adding a secret key instead of a connected account ID (looks like ‘acct_xxx’).

The issue you’re having looking for the Customer’s subscriptions list could be an API version issue - either too old to have that attribute, or newer/equal to 2020-08-27 when Stripe removed its contents to default calls, making you need to expand them.

It also looks like you’re making up methods which aren’t valid API paths for Stripe (like your customer.subscriptions.retrieve().delete()), but this might be my lack of Ruby knowledge.

Also, you have other options than looking at the Customer’s subscriptions attribute, you can also list Subscriptions by Customer (with a customer argument).

I think a lot of this can be resolved by looking up some Stripe official documentation.